# yii. как грамотно добавить объект в базу?

Tags: php, yii

Чувствую, что вопрос дурацкий. На примере: каталог товаров --> товар --> много характеристик. Как добавить товар и данные к нему, это понятно, для товара есть отдельный контроллер и модель. Контроллер в действии create передает модель во view, там CActiveForm разбирет его на кусочки и создаются новые поля. Но у товара есть свои характеристики. Как правильно добавить их? Создать в контроллере новую модель характеристики и там её разобрать? Каждый продукт имеет отношение к характеристике

```
'ch' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Characteristic', 'product_id')
```

можно ли оттуда достать эти характеристики и вывести их, чтобы можно было заполнить поля по одной? Как вообще лучше добавлять смежные данные через такую вот схему, где для одной записи в бд, нужно вывести данные другие и заполнить ещё несколько таблиц?

Answer (score 2):

[Сохранение связанных данных](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/model.save.related.data)

Comment: спасибо, отличная ссылка. правда, может быть не совсем то, что мне нужно

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понял что вам нада, но интуиция подсказывает вам нада технологию EAV - динамические атрибуты объекта. Кстати вот есть примеры [Динамические атрибуты для товаров (используем EAV в Yii)](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/31/dinamicheskie-atributi-dlia-tovarov-ispolzovanie-eav-v-yii)